# how to use router.push('/') in next.js server component?

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I have my `page.tsx` under appDir in Next.js 13 and it's a server component. But I have to use `router.push` for different reasons.

When I use it, this errors shows up `useRouter only works in Client Components`. How can I solve this? I can't add `'use client'` on top because I need it to be a server component. It's possible to use the router.push?

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `redirect()` function. For example: `redirect('/')`

Documentation: https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/redirect